# Как считать написанный текст через exec

Tags: java, bash, консоль, io

Добрый  вечер! Через `Runtime.exec` вызывается определенная Linux-программа, которая динамически отображает результат вот в таком виде (числа меняются с периодичностью 5-10 секунд):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое динамическое отображение добивается путем вставки текста в место для ввода текста. То есть текст вставляется в поле для ввода, а, при обновлении, стирается и вставляется снова. Тогда текст не "съезжает" вверх, а остается на одной строке.

---

Вопрос: каким образом можно считать этот текст любым методом (`Scanner`, `System.in` и т.д.)?

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.exec` возвращает вам объект класса `Process`. У этого объекта есть метод `getOutputStream()`, который и вернет вам искомый поток. Скорей всего вам придется обрабатывать команды для терминала, которые позволяют обновлять строку динамически.

Но лучше использовать `ProcessBuilder`, а не `Runtime.exec`. Этот класс позволяет детально описать как именно запустить процесс: в каком окружении, в какой момент и пр.

Comment: Но как с помощью `OutputStream` можно считать то, что программа записывает в поле для ввода? Мне кажется, что нужно что-то аналогичное `InputStream`.

Comment: @RostislavDugin как я вам и написал в ответе - вам надо анализировать команды, которые программа посылает в стандартный поток вывода (но команда может не использовать стандартный поток). Что за команду вы запускаете?

Comment: Запускаю `vnstat -l -i ens3` (`ens3` — сетевой интерфейс, обычно он обозначается как `eth0)`. Работает на Linux'e.